# How does z3's 'smt_tactic' solve QF_BV formulas?

Tags: z3, smt

When z3 uses `smt_tactic` (instead of the `qfbv` tactic) to solve a QF_BV formula, will it bit-blasts and uses the SAT engine? When I set verbose level to 10, I cannot see bit-blasting.

Answer (score 0):

It does bit-blasting, but lazily. It will use the SMT solver.
Note, however, that bit-blasting is quite eager, though.

Comment: Thanks. By "lazily", do you mean that the `smt_tacitc` will use a DPLL(T)-like abstraction-refinement loop when solving the QF_BV instance?

Comment: Exactly. If you build Z3 in debug mode and play with the -tr:foo options you can print in more detail what's going on. (and -v:999999 also helps).